# Making Graphics.drawLine follow mouse without extending

Tags: java, graphics, game-physics

I'm making a basic bubble shooter game to practice my coding and I am trying to make the pointer so that it will aim where I want it to shoot, I have the line movement to follow my mouse but it extends one it gets further away from the center. I want to turn almost like there is a pivot point.

```
public static void pointer(Graphics g) {
    g = panel.getGraphics();
    g.drawLine(325, 530, x, 450);
    g.fillRect(325, 530, x, 450);

}

public static void UI() {
    frame = new JFrame("Bubble shooter");
    panel = new JPanel();

    panel.setBackground(Color.white);
    panel.setLayout(null);

    frame.setSize(650,550);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    //frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    frame.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionListener() {

        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
            mouseMoving = true;

            x = e.getX();

            System.out.println("X: " + e.getX());
            System.out.println("Y: " + e.getY());

        }

    });
```

I am trying to make the line follow my mouse without growing or shrinking onto a pivot point. Instead, the line doesn't pass the set y coordinate but extends to follow the mouse.

Answer (score 0):

You have some errors in your code:

- You need to add panel to frame.
- You need to call your drawing method.
- You need to set color while drawing.
- You should calculate first point by current size of your panel instead of constant point.

Here is a working code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class MouseTest {
    int x = -1;
    int y = -1;

    public void pointer(Graphics g) {
        if (x < 0) {
            return;
        }
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        Rectangle bounds = g.getClipBounds();
        int startX = (int) (bounds.getWidth() / 2);
        int startY = (int) bounds.getHeight();
        g.drawLine(startX, startY, x, y);
    }

    public void UI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Bubble shooter");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel() {
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                pointer(g);
            }
        };

        panel.setBackground(Color.white);
        panel.setLayout(null);

        frame.setSize(650,550);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionListener() {
            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
                x = e.getX();
                y = e.getY();
                panel.repaint();
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MouseTest mouseTest = new MouseTest();
        mouseTest.UI();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you but I already have all that. I left a lot of code out since I didn't want to post the whole program.